# How can I prevent mouse clicks during Ubuntu screensaver from actually clicking the UI (for a touchscreen terminal)

Tags: ubuntu, screensaver, touchscreen, wake-up, mouse-click

This might be a dumb question...  I've got a touchscreen terminal set up for inventory tracking in my store.  I have a screensaver set up on it that appears after 2 minutes with a generic "touch the screen to continue" message.  When a user touches the screen during the screensaver, it not only closes the screensaver but it also clicks in the actual UI wherever they touched.  This leads to accidentally pushing buttons you don't want pushed, when all you were trying to do is kill the screensaver.

Any easy solutions to this?

Comment: Accidentally closing what UI?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, if you have control over the UI under the screensaver, you could have it have a timeout of the same length as the screensaver which makes it put up an overlay which catches one click, then disappears.

Also, have you checked whether your touchscreen is producing double-clicks?